# Alternative ways for getting content from http://<IP-Address>:8080/xyz/abc.html for an iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone suggest any alternative and best ways to get the content (HTML with references of scripts and styles) from a specific IP address using the HTTP protocol.

**considerations:**

1. My Website uses HTTPS protocol, which is hosted on the server whose IP-Address is different from the `<IP-Address>` specified above. eg. https://pqr.com
2. Not using `src="http://<IP-Address>:8080/xyz/abc.html"` in `IFrame` as this throws a `cannot load Mixed Active Content` error.
3. the `<IP-Address>` specified is of another device, where static **HTML, JS** and **CSS** files are present.
4. Backend(WebServer): ASP.Net MVC2
5. The only way to get the content is by using IP-Address, don't have a domain for the IP address.

**I'm facing the following issues:**

1. When the src of IFrame is set with the IP Address, the browser (Firefox) is disabling the content to load, this is expected as from Firefox 23 "mixed Active Content" loading is disabled by default. when disabling the warning, content loads perfectly well.
2. I tried to get the HTML pages using `WebRequest` in controller method, and writing back the HTML to IFrame, but because the HTML contains references to other CSS/Images/JS references getting all the content using `webrequest` again and replacing the references with code, will involve lot of string processing in the controller method.

Comment: Option 2 is your only option.

Comment: Can i achieve this using HTTPS proxy-server, separating the processing from the web-server code.